# Ajax call from local html page in Webkit Qt

Tags: ajax, qt, webkit

I'm trying to perform an Ajax/XMLHTTPrequest from within a local HTML file in QT 4.7RC QWebview. It consistently fails with an empty `responseText` and status 0. I've set the follwing

```
page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls,true);
```

but it has no effect (I can load remote images without problems though).

It seems to be a known issue and I'm not sure if there is a solution already.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31875

Any ideas for a workaround would be very helpful. Basically what I'm trying to do is running a HTML/Javascript WebApp in QWebview that talks to a local server at 127.0.0.0 and this problem is kind of a show-stopper. Interestingly, the actual query is sent and my server responds with 200 and the requested data. But the response never arrives in my Javascript callbacks.

Comment: are you sure AJAX doesn't require HTTP server for calls?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I call my own server via HTTP but the problem exists also when calling any other remote servers.

Comment: The same happens to me but only on Windows, the same code works just fine on Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question but are you sure that you are inside an AJAX security sandbox that works with webkit? In Firefox, IE and others using AJAXin different domains does not work. In fact,  http://demo1.demo.com is different than demo2.demo.com